# JDBC SQL select row between two dates

Tags: sql, jdbc

I have a table of the form:

```
===========================================================================================
test_id | type_id | patient_no | employee_no | medical_lab | result | pre_date | test_date 
===========================================================================================
```

The dates have this form: `2014-07-23 00:00:00` when examined in a result set.

This is the string that I execute in my statement object:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT TR.patient_no, P.name, TT.test_name, TR.test_date " +
"FROM patient P, test_type TT, test_record TR, doctor D " +
"WHERE TR.employee_no = " + doctorId +
"AND TR.type_id = TT.type_id " +
"AND P.health_care_no = TR.patient_no " +
"AND TRUNC(TR.prescribe_date) >= TO_DATE('" + initialDate + "', 'YYYY-MM-DD') " +
"AND TRUNC(TR.prescribe_date) <= TO_DATE('" + endDate + "', 'YYYY-MM-DD') " +
"ORDER BY TR.test_date ASC"
```

Now lets say I have three rows that I want to return ( I will only include relevant info in the example rows):

```
doctorId | prescriptionDate

12022,TO_DATE('2014-01-15','YYYY-MM-DD')
12022,TO_DATE('2014-07-15','YYYY-MM-DD')
12022,TO_DATE('2014-07-21','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Ok, so I want to return these three rows in my result set. So in my testing I set these variables and execute the statement:

```
initialDate = "2014-01-15"
endDate = "2014-07-21"
doctorId = "12022"
```

However, my result set will only contain the information from these two rows:

```
12022, 2014-07-15 00:00:00
12022, 2014-07-21 00:00:00
```

I've been trying to figure this out, but I really could use some help. Please and thank you.

p.s. I understand that my result set does not look like the one I've given in the example; however, the information in my result set is derived from these two rows (for the example given).

edit: trying to make my example "resultSet" more clear

Comment: What's the data type of `TR.prescribe_date`? `date` or `datetime`?

Comment: It's of the form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS I believe that is datetime?

Comment: Your query looks right to me. Are you sure the missing row satisfies `AND TR.type_id = TT.type_id AND P.health_care_no = TR.patient_no`?

Comment: I'm certain that the missing row should satisfy these constraints. However, I changed the query to just select the test date, and only satisfy the date constraints and the doctor id constraint, and yet the problem still persists. The problem is in the dates somehow.

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference, but try with `BETWEEN`, so something like `TRUNC(TR.prescribe_date) BETWEEN TRUNC(TO_DATE('" + initialDate + "', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AND TRUNC(TO_DATE('" + endDate + "', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))`.

Comment: I tried that and I even hardcoded in test dates, but I get the same result... it's very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in my query. The problem was in the way I viewed the result set:

```
while(result.next()){
  //various print statement
}
```

So, I always skipped first result... *facepalm* thanks for the help though isim.